# How to add passphrase to an RSA key?

Tags: rsa, public-key, passwords, xor, password-based-encryption

If I want to protect a private RSA key, do I just XOR the password into the key, or do I do something else? Is it secure?

Edit:
I got a good answer from a comment - Hash the password/passphrase with PBKDF and use that as a key for AES to encrypt the RSA private key. Also the passphrase is never stored on the disk. The user is prompted to enter it when starting the programm and it is stored in RAM for a limited amount of time(It will be overwritten later and RAM is cleared anyway on shutdown.)

Comment: a) **don't roll your own crypto.** b) this would be a vigenere chipher which is inherently broken c) normally you'd encrypt the private key with some trustworthy encryption algorithm like AES-GCM and derive a key for the algorithm using a proper PBKDF like Argon2, scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: Store it in a standard format, which supports the standard password-protection mechanisms. There are loads of libraries that can do that for you.

Comment: PGP would immediately come to mind. Note that I haven't checked upon the OpenPGP standard for some time; I'm not sure how secure it is. But in general using a strong password with key encryption should be fine for data-at-rest.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: **Don't roll your own crypto.**

As for your current approach: This is basically a vigenere cipher which is inherently broken, provides not integrity protection and wouldn't even encrypt known / predictable bit positions (where the ASCII code is constant zero or one).

As for an improved version:
Use a well-known encryption algorithm (e.g. AES-GCM) to encrypt and authenticate the key. Don't forget that you have to use a nonce (a number used only once) with it. Do not feed the user password directly into the cipher, but rather feed it into a proper *password based key derivation function* (PBKDF) (e.g. Argon2, scrypt, bcrypt, PBKDF2). Make sure you use a salt and that it is random and that the derivation parameters are so large that key access takes about 100ms of full CPU load on your system.

Comment: Another question: where is it ok to store the salt?

Comment: The passphrase is never stored on the disk. The user is prompted to enter it when starting the programm and it is stored in RAM for a limited amount of time(It will be overwritten later and RAM is cleared anyway on shutdown.)

Comment: @GordorJonathan, the salt doesn't need to be secret. You can store it in plain right next to your nonce / ciphertext (but please make sure to authenticate it as associated data with AES-GCM). But anyways please follow [Henno's advice](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35322/how-to-add-passphrase-to-an-rsa-key/35325?noredirect=1#comment82501_35322) if possible and don't roll your own crypto, but use some established key storage and format standard.

Comment: @GordorJonathan, that's sounds like a reasonable security practice regarding the passphrase although, may I suggest to use your favorite crypto libraries memory management functions to allocate the memory? (chances are it has some additional defenses built-in, f.ex. to tell the OS not to swap this portion of the memory out to disk)

Comment: Windows aint swap :D

Comment: Also, for the salt, I know a super-secure true-random number generator -- radioactive waste attached to radiactivity meter, the output of which is fed into the computer. You also need a proprietary driver for that. BTW the seed of Uranium is an infinity and seed of Plutonium is an infinitesimal.  Just a joke, althou radioactive true random is good practice for security :D